# Visual Studio 2005 extensions for .NET Framework 3.0 (WPF)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Did Microsoft abandon support for Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) on Visual Studio 2005?

There was the a Community Technology Preview (CTP) for the WPF and WCF, but [it's no longer available](http://tinyurl.com/5hn2yd) for download. There are [released extensions for Windows Workflow Foundation](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=5D61409E-1FA3-48CF-8023-E8F38E709BA6&displaylang=en) (WF) for Visual Studio 2005.

But as far as i can tell Microsoft abandoned support for WPF in Visual Studio 2005, and instead released them as Visual Studio 2008. Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately it looks like the extensions are no longer supported - see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/acangialosi/archive/2008/06/27/vs-2005-extensions-for-net-framework-3-0-wpf-wcf-ctp-is-coming-off-the-ms-download-center.aspx) MSDN blog post for further details.

Answer (score 4):

To quote the [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/acangialosi/archive/2008/06/27/vs-2005-extensions-for-net-framework-3-0-wpf-wcf-ctp-is-coming-off-the-ms-download-center.aspx) from "[Anthony @ MS](http://blogs.msdn.com/user/Profile.aspx?UserID=11698)" that [Stu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243843/visual-studio-2005-extensions-for-net-framework-30-wpf#243871) pointed out:

> **VS 2005 Extensions for .NET Framework 3.0 (WPF & WCF) CTP is Coming off the MS Download Center**
>
> In November 2006 Microsoft released a
>   CTP version of the VS 2005 Extensions
>   for .NET Framework 3.0 (WPF & WCF). 
>   We released this CTP as a stop gap to
>   provide developers the needed (albeit
>   very limited) set tools to start
>   developing for the .NET Framework 3.0.
>   This was never intended to release as
>   a complete product and was only
>   intended as a stop gap until Visual
>   Studio 2008, codenamed Orcas was
>   released.
>
> Since then Visual Studio 2008 has
>   released and SP1 is on the way.  With
>   VS 2008 you have a set of tools
>   designed entirely to take advantages
>   of the functionality introduced with
>   WCF & WPF.  Users who have been
>   developing using the CTP extensions
>   should have already migrated their
>   projects to VS 2008 to take advtange
>   of the new functionality which is far
>   better than what we were able to
>   deliver in the CTP.
>
> **On Monday, June 30th 2008, the license**
>   **for this CTP will expire.**  The
>   download will be removed from the MS
>   Download center. At that point any
>   existing users should work on
>   migrating their projects to VS 2008 to
>   take advantage of the fully supported
>   WPF & WCF support.
>
> Posted: Friday, June 27, 2008 11:34 AM

i guess it would have been nice of them to indicate up front that they had no intention of releasing a final form of the extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it never went beyond the CTP.

Only option is to handcrank beyond what the ctp provides.

I guess they want you to upgrade to VS 2008.